# Using ApplicationContextAware in Singleton class

Tags: spring, singleton, inject

I am trying to inject an object into a singleton class implementation. Something like this

```
public class MyObjectWrapper implements ApplicationContextAware {

    public static MyObject myObject;
    private ApplicationContext ctxt;
    private MyObjectWrapper() {}

    public static synchronized MyObject getImpl() {
        if (myObject!=null)
            return myObject;

        MyObjectWrapper myObjectWrapper=new MyObjectWrapper();
        this.myObject = (MyObject) myObjectWrapper.getCtxt().getBean("myobject");
        return myObject;
    }

    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext arg0)
            throws BeansException {
        logger.debug("setApplicationContext - " + arg0);
        this.ctxt = arg0;
    }

    public ApplicationContext getCtxt() {
        return ctxt;
    }

    public void setCtxt(ApplicationContext ctxt) {
        this.ctxt = ctxt;
    }

}
```

1. It doesnt work, that is when i call MyObjectWrapper.getImpl() i get a null MyObject. i have bean entries for myobject and MyObjectWrapper.
2. I know using getBean is not the best practice but in this particular example is it acceptable? What is the downside? If not here, i will being doing a similar getBean call in my Main method.

I can do a getBean in my main method (i am accessing the application context there), however i just wanted this Wrapper class to be responsible for creation of this singleton. Objects that need MyObject can just call MyObjectWrapper.getImpl() and they get a singleton object.

Any feedback on the same would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This won't work because you are instantiating a new instance of `MyWrapperObject` in your static `getInstance()` method.  Because you are instantiating it, the bean is ***NOT*** Spring managed, and therefore the `ApplicationContextAware` method, `setApplicationContext(...)`, will not be called by Spring.

I am not a fan of this code, but if you want to do something like this, I do have a suggestion.  Instead of saving the `ApplicationContext` to an instance member, save it to a static member.  Then, in your static `getInstance()` method, do not create a new instance of `MyWrapperObject`, just use the static `ApplicationContext` that you have to create the instance of `MyObject`.  If this class is indeed a Spring singleton, then you should have nothing to worry about.

Something like this:

```
public class MyObjectWrapper implements ApplicationContextAware {
    private static MyObject myObject;
    private static ApplicationContext ctxt;
    private MyObjectWrapper() {}

    public static synchronized MyObject getImpl() {
        if (myObject!=null)
            return myObject;

        this.myObject = ctxt.getBean("myobject", MyObject.class);
        return myObject;
    }

    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext arg0) throws BeansException {
        ctxt = arg0;
    }
}
```

Also, don't make your object `public`.  It is a singleton for a reason.  You want everyone that calls `getInstance()` to get the same instance of the object.  If you make it `public`, then anyone can get a hold of it and reassign it if they want.  It somewhat defeats the purpose...

Comment: I am facing the same issue and before reading the post, I struggled for a week. Even I implemented the same behavior, but no luck. The ctxt is never being shared between instances and always being null. By the way, I am doing this at a tomcat lib level and not at the war (app) level